# WordPress Dynamic Sidebars and Static Widgets

Tags: wordpress

I want to know whether what I am trying to do is best practice and also seek some advice on how to do it.

A website I am working on has some sidebars.  The content within them is pure HTML but the client would like the ability to manually update these as and when they choose.

They don't want to touch the code but they do want to swap the order and content of the sidebars as they see fit.

I was therefore wondering if the best way to do this is with a dynamic sidebar and widgets?

I know there is the 'Text' widget but this does not suit my needs as firstly the client should not touch the code, and secondly even if they did, that one piece of content could appear in numerous sidebars and would mean a lot of copying and pasting.

Ideally I would just like to wrap up the content into usefully named widgets and the client can just drop these in to the various sidebars as they please.

Is this the best approach?

If so what is the easiest way to create a widget with static content?

If not, then what is / are the alternative / s?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit dated question but i like to answer so others can find this later.

It sounds like you are going counter intuitive to why you use a wordpress installation, which is to let non programmers manage the content. From what you are asking does the theme you are using have designated sidebar areas? Or are they looking to have more?

I see two solutions really based on what I think you are asking. You could simply adjust the html in the theme to fit your formatting needs if its pretty standard and then the text widget will hold just the text they want to change and they can manage it.

If they have different formatting needs, for example the text could be a paragraph in one case and a table in the next, then you are probably better off creating custom widgets where the user can just change the text. For example your code for "table widget" would have the html formatting in the background `<table class='abc'`... and you would designate the user input fields for them to fill in the content when they use the widget and formatting is handled by the themes css class (or your own).

Now in regards to having to copy the same content there is already a plugin out there that will allow you to dupe a widget and its content that is already active on the site. You may be able to code this for yourself or look at the source out there for this.